# OpenCV Find_Package Emscripten - WebAssembly

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, emscripten, webassembly

I try to compile C++ program to WebAssembly - it is a wrapper over OpenCV C++ library

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_library(myProject STATIC myProject.cpp)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myProject ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

OpenCV is installed locally and it works fine when compiled with (CLion IDE)

```
cmake --build /Users/marek/Documents/projects/myProject/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 2
```

However, when I try to compile it with

```
mkdir build-wasm
cd build-wasm
cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR="/Users/marek/emsdk/node/8.9.1_64bit/bin/node" .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/marek/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.13/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake
```

it yields an error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names:

OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

So it does not locate OpenCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that your OpenCV installation was compiled for WebAssembly**:

This line means that CMake either does have some basic scripts installed, or you need to point to the directory in which your OpenCV installation *should* be:

> By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but CMake did not find one.

It is most-likely the case that you installed your OpenCV in a non-standard location. To be more specific about telling CMake where to look for you dependency, try the `HINTS` flag, under [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html?highlight=i#full-signature-and-config-mode).

---

**Most likely what is happening:**

There is a combination of bad error reporting, and a misunderstanding about how versatile `find_package` is in CMake. In essence, your OpenCV installation is not compiled for WebAssembly, so the library is invalid. CMake (or some sub-system) detected that the library was invalid, and errored out. However, the error message was missleading, in that it made it seem like you couldn't find the path to the OpenCV module. The best reporting CMake did was the following:

`If "OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.`

---

**EDIT**:

You can build OpenCV for WebAssembly from their [custom build script](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/platforms/js).

Comment: Yeah, I've eventually tried their script and it worked, however it generates a 10MB js file. Do you how can I create bindings just for selected modules and not the whole library?

Comment: @Marek You use their raw build script? As in, you just ran it verbatim?

Comment: I've just ran python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_wasm --build_wasm --enable_exception --emscripten_dir=/path/to/emcc